# Window.open() not working on google chrome

Tags: javascript, vue.js, window.open

In my vue.js application I am trying to open a new tab trough `window.open()` but whenever I do that the a new tab opens and immediately closes before loading anything at all. `window.open()` works just fine on Firefox and `window.location.replace` also works normally.

Why is `window.open()` not working?

```
openWindow(info) {
      window.open('http://10.100.100.100:9999/window?someInfo=' + info);
    },
```

PS: I also tried the following code just to see what happens and it worked just fine.

```
openWindow(info) {
      window.open("http://www.google.com");
    },
```

Comment: Try passing in "_blank" as a second parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

It appears you need the second param.

```
window.open(url, windowName, [windowFeatures]);

openWindow(info) {
      window.open('http://10.100.100.100:9999/window?someInfo=' + info, '_blank');
    },
```

Comment: I'll try ti at work tomorrow. However does that explain why the second method works but not the first one?

Comment: Well I would assume that it has something to do with firefox's interpretation of window.open() with 1 parameter. Since it is not officially supported, it's hard to say. Your better off including more parameters such as a target location and some windows params to offer a better UX. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features

Comment: Good day. I am at worked and tried this but it didnt work

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant but yesterday we were trying to add ssl certificates to the site so it could turn into a https site. Now window open ain't working. the ip address in the window.open function i also not the same one as the main web page.

Answer (score 2):

I was lodged here on search.

**I faced such issue only on mobile chrome.**

The two param didn't work for me. **So i used 3 params.**

```
openWindow(info) {
 window.open('http://10.100.100.100:9999/window?someInfo=' + info, '_blank', 'popup=1');
}
```

or

```
openWindow(info) {
 window.open('http://10.100.100.100:9999/window?someInfo=' + info, '_blank', '');
}
```